# How to create UPDATE from exported data?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to get data from one database..table into an UPDATE script that can be used with another database..table.  Rather than doing export from DB1 into DB2, I need to run an UPDATE script against DB2.

If the above is not possible, is there a way to generate the UPDATE syntax from DB1..table1:

```
col1 = value1,
col2 = value2,
col3 = value3,
...
```

--- EDIT ---

Looking through the answers, there's an assumption that DB1 is available at the same time that DB2 is available.  This is not the case.  Each database will know nothing of the other.  The two servers/databases will not be available/accessible at the same time.

Is it possible to script the table data into a flat file?  Not sure how easy that will be to then get into an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Using linked server, you can UPDATE data (DML) from one db to another.

Comment: Linked server implies both servers are available at the same time.  In this case, they are not.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a linked server and an update statement will really be your easiest solution as stated above, but I do understand that sometimes that isn't possible.  The following is an example of dynamically building update statements.  I am assuming there is no chance of SQL Injection from the "SourceData" table.  If there is that possibility then you will need to use the same technique to build statements that use sp_executesql and parameters.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE UpdateTable ' +
    '  SET FieldToUpdate1 = ''' + SourceData.DataToUpdate1 + '''' +
    '     , FieldToUpdate2 = ' + CAST(SourceData.DataToUpdate2 AS varchar) +
    ' WHERE UpdateTable.PrimaryKeyField1 = ' + CAST(SourceData.PrimaryKey1 AS varchar) +
    '   AND UpdateTable.PrimaryKeyField2 = ''' + SourceData.PrimaryKey2 + ''''
FROM SourceData
```

Also here is a link to a blog I wrote on [Generating multiple SQL statements from a query](http://sqlstudies.com/2012/12/17/generating-multiple-sql-statements-from-a-query/).  It's a bit more simplistic than the type of statement you are trying to create, but it should give you an idea.  Also here is an article I wrote on using [Single Quotation Marks in SQL](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/95670/).  Other than that you can go onto Google and search for "SQL Server Dynamic SQL" and you will get hundreds of blogs, articles, forum entries etc on the subject.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to construct that?  There are many columns in the table.

Comment: I'll edit my query with a couple extra fields in both the SET part and the WHERE part.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs a little more clarification to be completely understand what you are trying to accomplish, but assuming the databases are on the same server, then you should be able to do something like this using `UPDATE` and `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE a
SET col1 = value1, col2 = value2
FROM database1.schema.table a
    JOIN database2.schema.table b
        ON a.primaryKey = b.primaryKey
```

Alternatively, if they are on different servers, you could setup a linked server and it should work similarly.

Comment: Both databases will not be available at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still want to `INSERT` from one table into another table of another database. You can use `INSERT INTO..SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.TableName(Col1, Col2, Col3) -- specify columns
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM   DB1.dbo.TableName
```

Assuming `dbo` is the schema used.

Answer (score 0):

Are both databases on the same SQL-Server?  In that case, use fully-qualified table names.  I.e.:

```
Update Database1.Schema.Table
SET ...
FROM
Database2.Schema.Table
```

If they're not on the same server, then you can use `linked servers`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the SQL server syntax but you can do something like this to generate the update statement.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE mytable SET col1=' || col1 || ' WHERE pk=' primaryKey ||';' FROM mytable;
```

Obviously you'll need to escape quotes, etc. depending on the value types.

I assume this is because you can't do a normal UPDATE from a SELECT?

Comment: It's because the two servers will not be available/accessible at the same time.